# Can we start dense_rank() with any given number in pyspark or python?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I am trying to generate the dense_rank() based on value of one column but I want to generate dense_rank() starting with given input number. Is this possible in pyspark or in python?

Example:

code I am using to generate dense_rank() in pyspark:

```
if(masterjobname == 'IM_XREF_BRIDGE_ADDR'):
            df = sqlContext.sql(query)
            print("Target:  "+targetpath )
            w = (Window().orderBy("SOURCE_COLUMN_VALUE"))
            df = df.withColumn("SYSTEM_ID", dense_rank().over(w))
            cols = list(df.columns)
            cols = cols[-1:] + cols[:-1]
            df = df[cols]

SYSTEM_ID    
 1
 2
 2
 3
 4
 4
 5
```

so here max dense_rank is 5

In above example dense_rank is starting from 1 so I want dense_rank starting with (5+1) in the next run.

Expected output:
suppose I want to start dense_rank with 10.

```
SYSTEM_ID    
     6
     7
     7
     8
     9
     9
     10
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store the max value of the ranks you already have in your column, and add that value to the column in the next run.

Let me show you what I ended up doing with two different dataframes, maybe you can use it.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import dense_rank, lit

w1 = Window.partitionBy('some_column').orderBy('some_column')
df1 = df.withColumn(
    'rank', dense_rank().over(w1)
)

prev_max = df1.select(f.max(f.col('rank'))).collect()[0][0]

w2 = Window.partitionBy('other_column').orderBy('other_column')
df = df.withColumn(
    'other_rank', dense_rank().over(w2) + lit(prev_max)
)
```